# Facebook Graph - Grab most recent X posts?

Tags: jquery, json, facebook-graph-api

I've been looking at the [Facebook Graph API for reading a Page's Posts](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/), but I can't seem to figure out how to limit it to the most recent X posts. For example, the [Facebook Platform Page's JSON](https://graph.facebook.com/platform/posts) returns a whole crap-ton of posts. I'm only going to be displaying the most recent 5 posts, so I don't see a reason to load any more than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the option of limit:

https://graph.facebook.com/platform/posts?limit=5

Source:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api

Comment: Thank you, MrCrapper! I was looking in the wrong places in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

"limit=5" mean limit only 5 entry per page
limit should use together with offset for pagination

you can try "until" and/or "since" parameter to get recently entry via graph api 
example "since=yesterday" = get recent entry since yesterday

--- example ---

```
http://graph.facebook.com/comments?since=yesterday&ids=http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/
```

you can use

- since=today
- since=yesterday
- until=today
- until=yesterday
- or use unix timestamp for specific date

if you have many new entry per day (over 25 entry) graph api will break your entry into a page so if you dont want paging you can use "limit=10000" then all entry show in 1 page

documents here

```
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/
```

test your api here

```
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer
```